# Diagonals of a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, diagonal

Is there a more pythonic way of doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
def diagonal(A):
    (x,y,y) = A.shape
    diags = []
    for a in A: diags.append(np.diagonal(a))
    result = np.vstack(diags)
    assert result.shape == (x,y)
    return result
```

Comment: Please expand on what `A` is. Are you assuming it is an `n * m * m` matrix?

Comment: @evan058 Yes, I tried to communicate that assumption with the first line of my diagonal() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

A *clean* way would be with [`np.diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) on a transposed version of input array, like so -

```
np.diagonal(A.T)
```

Basically, we are flipping the dimensions of the input array with `A.T` to let `np.diagonal` use the last two axes for extracting the diagonal elements along, because by default it would have otherwise used the first two axes instead. The best thing is this would work for arrays of any number of dimensions.

**Approach #2**

Here's another approach using a combination of [`advanced and basic indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) -

```
m,n = A.shape[:2]
out = A[np.arange(m)[:,None],np.eye(n,dtype=bool)]
```

One can also use some reshaping with `basic indexing` -

```
out = A.reshape(m,-1)[:,np.eye(n,dtype=bool).ravel()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [87]: A
Out[87]: 
array([[[73, 52, 62],
        [20,  7,  7],
        [ 1, 68, 89]],

       [[15, 78, 98],
        [24, 22, 35],
        [19,  1, 91]],

       [[ 5, 37, 64],
        [22,  4, 43],
        [84, 45, 12]],

       [[24, 45, 42],
        [70, 45,  1],
        [ 6, 48, 60]]])

In [88]: np.diagonal(A.T)
Out[88]: 
array([[73,  7, 89],
       [15, 22, 91],
       [ 5,  4, 12],
       [24, 45, 60]])

In [89]: m,n = A.shape[:2]

In [90]: A[np.arange(m)[:,None],np.eye(n,dtype=bool)]
Out[90]: 
array([[73,  7, 89],
       [15, 22, 91],
       [ 5,  4, 12],
       [24, 45, 60]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `A` will be an array with shape (m, n, n) (i.e. `A` can be interpreted as a collection of `m` arrays with shape `(n, n)`), here's a fast method that returns a *view* of the input:

```
In [14]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

In [15]: def diags(a):
   ....:     b = as_strided(a, strides=(a.strides[0], a.strides[1]+a.strides[2]), shape=(a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))
   ....:     return b
   ....: 

In [16]: a
Out[16]: 
array([[[8, 6, 6, 5],
        [1, 0, 3, 5],
        [8, 1, 6, 7],
        [2, 8, 7, 1]],

       [[0, 8, 8, 0],
        [1, 4, 2, 4],
        [1, 4, 5, 6],
        [2, 5, 2, 7]],

       [[5, 2, 5, 2],
        [2, 5, 7, 6],
        [6, 5, 1, 8],
        [7, 6, 5, 8]]])

In [17]: diags(a)
Out[17]: 
array([[8, 0, 6, 1],
       [0, 4, 5, 7],
       [5, 5, 1, 8]])
```

When I say the return value is a *view*, I mean it refers to the same underlying memory as the input.  So if you later change the return value in-place, the original input also changes.  For example,

```
In [24]: d = diags(a)

In [25]: d[0, :] = 99

In [26]: a[0]
Out[26]: 
array([[99,  6,  6,  5],
       [ 1, 99,  3,  5],
       [ 8,  1, 99,  7],
       [ 2,  8,  7, 99]])
```

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty pythonic.

Comment: With that said, it doesn't look particularly clean or intuitive. Is there a better way?

Comment: "clean", "intuitive", "better"... it depends on your definition of those words.  Having said that, @Divakar's answer looks pretty good (as usual!), especially Approach #1.  I don't think you can get much cleaner than that.